# Refresh Multiple iframes

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have a little project to do, and want to display multiple pages using iframe. So on my main HTML page i need 4 iframes, and ive got them to refresh. just id like to make the code to tidier and access the iframes another way to what i have done here:

```
 function refresh() 
   {
     var iframe = document.getElementById('website1');
     iframe.src = iframe.src;
     setTimeout('refresh()',refreshCycleTime);

     var iframe2 = document.getElementById('website2');
     iframe2.src = iframe2.src;
     setTimeout('refresh()',refreshCycleTime);

     var iframe3 = document.getElementById('website3');
     iframe3.src = iframe3.src;
     setTimeout('refresh()',refreshCycleTime);

     var iframe4 = document.getElementById('website4');
     iframe4.src = iframe4.src;
     setTimeout('refresh()',refreshCycleTime);
   }
```

I tried having the website1, website2, webiste3... all in one getElementById, but thinking about it the getbyID will only work for one element. So is there another solution that i could use here?

I have tried applying a class to the iframes rather than id, then use the getelementsbyclass name method, but that didn't work for me.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of those `iframe.src = iframe.src;` lines?

Comment: If you want to use plain JavaScript as suggested in you question (but not in your tags) you can put `document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[i].src=` … `;` in a for loop using the variable `i` to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `each` and `iframe` selector:

```
  function RefreshIframes(){
     $("iframe").each(function() { 
          var src= $(this).attr('src');
         $(this).attr('src',src);  
     });
  }

  setInterval(function(){ 
      RefreshIframes();
  }, 1000);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/143orcmn/

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

So I have this in my code now and it doesn't work. have I done something wrong?

function refresh() 
      {
        $('iframe').each(fuction()
        {
        //$(this).src = $(this).src;// not sure if this makes sense?
        $(this).contentDocument.location.reload(true);  
        setTimeout('refresh()',refreshCycleTime);    
        });
      }


Cheers